# How to set a custom page to replace the default Firefox New Tab page

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox 40, and I don't really like the `New Tab` page, so I would really like to set it to the DuckDuckGo homepage, how can this be achieved so that when I click the New Tab button I get the DuckDuckGo homepage?

I have already done some research into this, but [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customize-new-tab-page?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=new-tab-page-show-hide-and-customize-top-sites) is all that I found. And I am not looking for a way of customizing the look of the default `New Tab` page, so not pinning the tiles, nor rearranging them etc, no, instead I am looking to replace the `New Tab` page with another page. And I could not find any information on achieving this.

**Information Update:**

I have recently upgraded to Firefox 41, and the solution [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1013039) no longer works for I cannot see the `browser.newtab.url` option. Has it moved or something or is this simply no longer achievable?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: @MartyFried: Quoting the [on-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) section of the help centre: `Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.`.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1013039

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: Can you post that as an answer please so that I can accept it. :)

Comment: As you wish, hope it helps others

Comment: I agree with Marty Fried. The question has nothing to do with Ubuntu even tangentially. While it maybe on-topic as per the FAQ, I think superuser.com would be a more appropriate site for this question.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda: I think "running 3rd party apps" refers not to the app itself so much as running the app - ie, when you are having trouble getting the app to run, or getting the Ubuntu-specific configuration set up.  As you know, the answer to this particular question came from the Mozilla site.  You probably searched there for the answer, just as the OP should have done.

Comment: @MartyFried: Well, I have seen a large amount of questions on this site about how to do things in third-party apps, and in fact these questions don't have anything really to do with Ubuntu usually as the software is not Ubuntu-specific, however these questions are still allowed so I don't see the problem with mine here.

Comment: @MartyFried I'd welcome comment here http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14382/

Comment: @Oli: FWIW, I wasted a bit of time with my take on the issue.  Wasted, because I see the first and only answer that agreed with the OP was accepted as the "answer."  I don't think anyone really understood my reasons, although that could be my own fault for not explaining better.  PS, where's *your* comment?  ;-)

Comment: @Oli: Oops, sorry, I somehow missed that it was you that "answered".  Well, I guess **I disagree with that**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox **41** `browser.newtab.url` preference is missing in `about:config`.

Firefox 40 or versions prior to it allowed users to replace the New Tab Page with a custom web page or site like Google.com by changing the `browser.newtab.url` preference value in `about:config` to a desired URL.

From firefox 41 onwards you have to use the [New Tab Override (browser.newtab.url replacement)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-override/) to make changes to the New Tab.

1. Download and install the add-on.

[image]

2. Visit add-ons  manager, click on its ‘Options’, enter the URL in place of `about:newtab` for which you want the new tab to open.

[image]

3. Click ‘OK’ - then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open the new tab page to see if it is loading the site you’ve set above in the extension’s options.

**PLEASE** refer [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1084095)

Comment: I am unable to see the images...

Comment: Also, why is this so? Why did they decide to do this?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I believe. I don't know "why"? I will try to figure it out:)

Comment: @ParanoidPanda images?

Comment: It says "Imgur" in two places in your question just as text, and when looking in [edit] it says that there are links but with this for `![Imgur](URL)`.

Answer (score 4):

**Please note that this answer only works for Firefox version 40 and below.**

---

From https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1013039

> In case you need more of a step-by-step:
>
> 1. In a new tab, type or paste `about:config` in the address bar and
>      press Enter. Click the button promising to be careful.
> 2. In the search box above the list, type or paste `newtab` and pause
>      while the list is filtered
> 3. Double-click the `browser.newtab.url` preference and enter your
>      preferred page:
>
>    ```
>    Page thumbnails (default)    =>   about:newtab 
>    Blank tab                    =>   about:blank
>    Built-in Firefox home page   =>   about:home 
>    Any other page               =>   full URL to> the page
>    ```
>
> Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab and verify that it worked.